# "Button.performclick()" vs"Call Button_Click(sender, e)"

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between `Button.performclick()` vs `Call Button_Click(sender, e)`? When should I use which one (if it matters in the first place)?

Comment: `when should I use which one` use neither or eventually you will be wanting to differentiate between real clicks and your calls.  Put the code in a method and call it from the button click and from your code in place of `perform..`

Answer (score 2):

[PerformClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method by which the control will raise the click event where as `Button_Click(sender, e)` is the event's method event handler. Both will probably do what are wanting to do.

Personally, I would suggest using the neither and instead wrap the code in the Click event into a sub, then calling the Sub in the Click event and calling the Sub in in lieu of the PerformClick.

Answer (score 1):

`Call` exists mainly for compatibility when updating older VB6-era code to VB.Net. There's no good reason to use it in VB.Net.

That said, I almost never use `performClick()`. If I need to manually call the button click code from elsewhere I tend to either just write `Button_Click(sender, e)` (no `Call`) or, even better, create a new method to host the button click code, so both the button click event and my other code will call this new method instead.